# R: Joining two dataframes based on ID and time with sqldf

Tags: r, left-join, sqldf

I am trying to join two data frames. In the first I do have a time variable (`StartSession`), in the other data frame I have two time variables (`Start`, `End`) marking the start and endtime of the possible time-window for StartSession to fall in-between. I want to join the two data frames based on the ID of each participant when `StartSession` of df1 is between `Start` and `End` of df2. Not for each case in df1 there is data in df2.

I searched for solutions and came across `sqldf()`, so I tried to do it with `sqldf left join`. But it does not work, I don't have an error message but on the right side of df1 there are the column names of df2 but without data (`NA`).
Can you help me? I am sorry if something is unclear, I am really a beginner in R and I am glad to provide more information if necessary.

```
data = sqldf("SELECT * FROM df1
                   left JOIN df2
                   ON df1.ID = df2.ID
                   AND df1.StartSession BETWEEN df2.Start and df2.End",
                   method = "name__class")
```

Reproduce dataset

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Session = c(3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7), StartSession = structure(c(1601943118, 
1602022814, 1602107392, 1602634216, 1602891080, 1601930068, 1602187292, 
1602278537, 1602526192, 1602979765), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), Start = structure(c(1601935128, 
1601935317, 1602015011, 1602099592, 1602626414, 1602883278, 1601922271, 
1602099313, 1602179494, 1602270739), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), End = structure(c(1601936456, 1601936602, 1602016298, 
1602100887, 1602627696, 1602884626, 1601923578, 1602100759, 1602180771, 
1602272006), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

*Sample Data*

```
df1
ID   StartSession
01   2020-10-06 20:08:11
01   2020-10-07 15:18:12
01   2020-10-08 18:23:34
02   2020-10-07 19:45:23
03   2020-10-08 20:30:24
03   2020-10-08 23:48:02

df2
ID     Start                  End
01   2020-10-06 20:05:11    2020-10-06 20:15:11
01   2020-10-07 15:14:12    2020-10-07 15:24:12
02   2020-10-07 19:42:23    2020-10-07 19:52:23
03   2020-10-08 20:26:24    2020-10-08 20:36:24
03   2020-10-08 23:44:02    2020-10-08 23:54:02
```

Result should be:

```
data
ID     StartSession           Start                  End
01     2020-10-06 20:08:11    2020-10-06 20:05:11    2020-10-06 20:15:11
01     2020-10-07 15:18:12    2020-10-07 15:14:12    2020-10-07 15:24:12
01     2020-10-08 18:23:34    NA                     NA
02     2020-10-07 19:45:23    2020-10-07 19:42:23    2020-10-07 19:52:23
03     2020-10-08 20:30:24    2020-10-08 20:26:24    2020-10-08 20:36:24
03     2020-10-08 23:48:02    2020-10-08 23:44:02    2020-10-08 23:54:02
```

Comment: Just a guess but maybe your datetime columns are POSIXct.  In that case you specified name__class which requires that you specify the classes but you did not do so.  Remove the method= argument if that is the case.  Also please use `dput` to show the input as requested at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.

Comment: Thanks @G.Grothendieck. I checked and the datetime columns are POSIXct. I removed the method argument, but it does not change the output. Should I change the format of the datetime?

Comment: You will need to follow the instructions in the last sentence of my comment.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Sorry, I added the output of dput for the first ten rows.

Comment: Probably I see the problem now. When opening just `df1` and `df2` the values of `StartSession` are in the intervalls between `Start` and `End` of `df2`. But after running the `sqldf` command, in the `data` output all the `StartSession` are 2 hours later than in the original `df1` and therefore outside of the interval.

Comment: Your data frames are using different time zones.  Suggest you set your session time zone to GMT (or equivalently UTC) to avoid such problems or else ensure that they use the same time zones in both or else use character rather than POSIXct. There are other ways around this as well discussed in the sqldf issues: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf/issues/10 .